# Geoserver MVT v2

Tags: geoserver, vector-tiles

Is there a geoserver extension (2.13.x) to generate MVT in spec v2 or some plan to include it within the extension or other plugins that allow to generate mvt v2?

Answer (score 1):

The [GeoServer documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/extensions/vectortiles/tutorial.html#vector-tile-formats) lists the formats that are supported:

> GeoServer can produce vector tiles in three formats: GeoJSON, TopoJSON, and MapBox Vector (MVT). These are also supported by OpenLayers 3 and other clients.

Comment: Hi Ian, I know that, but it seems that the MVT version is not v2, and it produces errors, for example, in recent mapbox-gl library versions...

Comment: We're always happy to accept code contributions to fix an issue you may have. Or you can update the documentation to reflect the version supported.

Answer (score 0):

We've started using: [tile.stream](https://www.tile.stream) you upload our gis files and get an endpoint to get Vector Tiles, super simple.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).